# How to get value from radiobutton in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, radio-button, groupbox

I have lots of radiobutton in groupbox and I want to get radiobutton's text data which is checked. However I dont want to write lots of "else if", what I mean is;

```
if (ui->radiobutton->isChecked)
// method's 
else if (ui->radiobutton->isCheked)
// method's 
..
..
```

Is there any way that I can understand which radiobutton is checked inside specific groupbox ? If possible could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a QButtonGroup as the parent: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#checkedButton

> QAbstractButton * QButtonGroup::checkedButton() const
>
> Returns the button group's checked button, or 0 if no buttons are
>   checked.
>
> See also buttonClicked().

Comment: This will work. Just add your buttons to the QButtonGroup and then use the code above.